# Second $or Failing in Spring boot with mongodb template

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, mongodb-query

MongoDB Shell Script Query working but it's not working with spring boot, could anyone please help to resolve this:

```
{
"State":{"$ne":"Created"},
"$or":[{"$and":[{"Type":"36"},{"SubType":"01"}]} , {"$and":[{"Type":"36"},{"SubType":"01"}]}],
"$or":[{"$and":[{"name":"Peter"},{"type":"UW"}]} , {"$and":[{"name":"Peter"},{"type":"UW"}]}]
}
```

Same logic i'm trying to write with spring boot but giving the error like **below.org.springframework.data.mongodb.InvalidMongoDbApiUsageException: Due to limitations of the com.mongodb.BasicDocument, you can't add a second 'null' criteria. Query already contains '{ "$or" : [{ "$and" : [{ "name" : "Danvers"}, { "type" : "UW"}]}]}'**

```
Criteria criteria = Criteria.where("State").ne("Created");
Query query = new Query();
                
List<Criteria> orExpression1 = new ArrayList<>();
List<Criteria> orExpression2 = new ArrayList<>();

orExpression1.add(new Criteria().andOperator(Criteria.where("Type").is("36"));

query.addCriteria(new Criteria().orOperator(orExpression1.toArray(new Criteria[orExpression1.size()])));

orExpression2.add(new Criteria().andOperator(Criteria.where("name").is("Peter"),Criteria.where("type").is("UW")));

query.addCriteria(new Criteria().orOperator(orExpression2.toArray(new Criteria[orExpression2.size()])));
```

Comment: create one `or` combine two `or` together and try again

Comment: No @mohammadNaimi - i wanna multiple $or conditions inside $and like below  {
$and: [
{$or : [{"$and":[{"a":"36"},{"b":"01"}]} , {"$and":[{"a":"36"},{"b":"01"}]}],
{$or : [{"$and":[{"c":"Peter"},{"d":"UW"}]} , {"$and":[{"e":"Peter"},{"f":"UW"}]}
]}

Comment: how can i write this thing in spring boot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution, by using Aggregation API with match operation , below one sample spring boot query output

```
  { "aggregate" : "__collection__", "pipeline" : [
 
 { "$match" : { "$and" : [{ "InceptionDate" : { "$gte" : "2021-09-05T00:00:00", "$lte" : "2022-02-28T23:59:59"}}, { "RenewalState" : { "$ne" : "Created"}}]}},
 
 { "$match" : { "$or" : [{ "$and" : [{ "type" : "36"}, { "subtype" : "01"}]}, { "$and" : [{ "type" : "45"}, { "subtype" : "19"}]}]}}, 
 
 { "$match" : { "$or" : [{ "$and" : [{ "contacts.name" : "Peter"}, { "contacts.type" : "UW"}]}, { "$and" : [{ "contacts.name" : "Ross"}, { "contacts.type" : "UW"}]}]}}, 
 
 { "$skip" : 0}, { "$limit" : 10}, { "$sort" : { "policyInformation.policyNumber" : 1}}]}}
```